# How to use Alarm Manager for repeating method execute function?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I used the [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) as such ,

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(G.context, ActivityAlarm.class);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(G.context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

I don't want to open an Activity just execute a static/non-static method during this time interval.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(G.context, **my method**);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(G.context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Is it possible to achieve this using the AlarmManager?

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to do this task:

1) **Simple Thread**

2) **Timer or Timertask**

3) **ScheduledExecutorService**

For more details see [here](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/04/java-how-to-schedule-a-task-to-run-in-an-interval.html)